# How to setup Polymer-based project?

Tags: polymer

i found this project on Github: https://github.com/RobinLinus/websecurity-quiz. I would like to use it for my own project but i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

I use "npm", i did everything in Polymer Guide but i can't use above project.

**This is what I did:**

```
npm install -g polymer-cli
polymer init starter-kit

mkdir myapp
cd myapp

polymer serve --open
```

And i got blank page without content.

Can someone guide me step-by step on how to setup this project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have it in slightly the wrong order.

```
mkdir myapp
cd myapp
polymer init starter-kit
polymer serve --open
```